# WASAdmin doesn't appear to be working on IHS8/WAS8

Tags: websphere, ibmhttpserver

I installed IHS and then configured the admin service, however, now when I try to access it using websphere 8.5 it fails

When I try to start

> com.ibm.ws.management.webserver.ServerNotAvailableException: start No Connection

When I try to reach config

> [1/10/14 17:15:24:868 EST] 0000006f SystemOut     O IOException java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

and when I access through a browser I get the following...

```
[Fri Jan 10 16:28:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/apache
```

This is clearly wrong as i do not have a c:\apache but I cannot figure what is configured wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was something with the proxy at work. When I edited my Hosts to direct my domain requests to 127.0.0.1 instead of leaving it up to the DNS it worked!